# How much rep do you need to vote in the 2011 election?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, election

What is the minimum reputation required to vote in the 2011 election?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the election phase, 10 candidates advance to final community voting. Any community member with **150 reputation** may vote in the election.

Each community member has 3 votes. Please cast your votes in order of preference, starting with the most desirable candidate first.

All candidates are displayed in random order.

The vote tallies are private until the election is complete.

**Please Note:** The above rules were applicable for the Jan/Feb-2011 moderator elections.

Comment: Thanks for that. I see I have to click the tabs on the election page to get the extra details for each stage - doh. I see you need 150 rep to vote in the primary too.

Comment: It's 12 candidates advancing to the elections.

Comment: @casperOne, it's 12 candidates for the Nov 2011 election, but it was 10 candidates in the Jan/Feb 2011 election.

Comment: @PopularDemand: That should be reflected in the answer, as the question is ambiguous at best.

Comment: Yeah, but when the question was asked, the Nov 2011 election didn't exist yet. And the actual answer to the question hasn't changed; only the additional info has.

Comment: @PopularDemand - Have added a note at the end of answer to reflect the answer is applicable to only Jan/Feb-2011 elections.

Comment: The answer is still applicable to this current election — the rep requirement hasn't changed from the previous one. If you didn't just quote the entire info box full of irrelevant information and only referenced the single sentence that directly answers the question, there wouldn't be any ambiguity.